# SQL view - how to set the value of one column (append a number) based on a count of another column?

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [UAT]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vwVOUCHER_EXPORT]    Script Date: 2/6/2019 1:35:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwVOUCHER_EXPORT] AS
SELECT [VOUCHER].[ID] 
      ,[VOUCHER].[EMP_ID] 
      ,[VOUCHER].[DATE_TO_PAY]
      ,[VOUCHER_PAYMENT].[PAYEE_NAME]
      ,[VOUCHER_PAYMENT].[BANK_ACCOUNT_ID] 
      ,[VOUCHER_PAYMENT].[VENDOR_ADDRESS_ID]    
      ,[VOUCHER].[PAYMENT_METHOD]   

FROM VOUCHER            
    INNER JOIN VOUCHER_STATUS ON VOUCHER.VOUCHER_STATUS_ID = VOUCHER_STATUS.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VOUCHER_PAYMENT ON VOUCHER.ID = VOUCHER_PAYMENT.VOUCHER_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BANK_ACCOUNT ON VOUCHER.EMP_ID = BANK_ACCOUNT.EMP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VENDOR ON VOUCHER.PAYEE_VENDOR_ID = VENDOR.ID



GO
```

I am using MS SQL Server 13. With this view I am returning payment details. Each EMP_ID can have multiple bank_account_ids, and vendor_address_ids. The payment method types are EQPMWT, EQPMMC, and EQPMAH. In the attached screen schot, you can see that they could have two bank account ids, and or, two vendor_address_ids. I need to append a number to the PAYMENT_METHOD field value EQPMWT, EQPMMC, and EQPMAH base on the numeric value of the bank_account_id and the vendor_address_id asc

Attached is a screen of what this query returns and as well as what I need. [image: what I have]

[image: what I need]

This view is being used to generate XML for another system. I don't want to change the value of this field in the db, only in this view.

I hope this is a little more clear. Thank you.

Comment: In order to get a proper answer, please share sample data, expected output, and complete SQL code.

Comment: Please provide your table structures for a definitive answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Have I provided enough information and structure to remove the on hold status? Please let me know if you need something more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Update T1 Set PaymentMethod = 'EPMWT' + Convert(Varchar(100), T2.Cnt
   From Table1 T1
   Join (Select Emp_Id, Count(*) Cnt From Table2 Group By Emp_Id) T2 On T2.Emp_Id = T1.Emp_Id
```

I would like to note that I would not design the structure this way.  I would have the value derived at the time of a query (maybe in a view) using a similar syntax to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CASE WHEN`, you can just concatenate count to result

```
select CONCAT('EPMWT', COUNT([BANK_ACCOUNT].[EMP_ID]))
```

if you dont want to use `Group by`, you can use window functions

```
select CONCAT('EPMWT', COUNT([BANK_ACCOUNT].[EMP_ID]) over ())
```

inside over clause you need to pass grouping operator

```
count([BANK_ACCOUNT].[EMP_ID]) OVER (PARTITION BY <grouping_column>)
```

Comment: This worked well to add the count to the EPMWT value, example EPMWT2. Thank you. I need something more now. Is it possible get the EPMWT2 to be EPMWT1 (for bank_account_id=7202) and EPMWT2 (for bank_account_id=7203) ?